# In how many ways can $10$ different books be distributed to $3$ students?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can $10$ different books be distributed to $3$ students so that each student receives at least one book ?

---

Although I did solve by using Binomial Distribution, but just for curiosity -->

Is Sterling's Formula applicable for such problems ?

How can I apply Sterling's formula of 2nd kind here ?

---

My Question is also a possible duplicate of below question and I am very well aware of this method.

[Distribution of 10 different books to three students.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747194/distribution-of-10-different-books-to-three-students)

I am just interested in knowing whether Sterling formula of 2nd kind applicable ?

Comment: Hint : There are $3^{10}$ ways to distribute the $3$ books over the students without the ristriction that each student must receive at least one book. Now, calculate the number of ways , we can distribute the books over $2$ students ($1$ student is trivial)

Comment: The number of ways to partition n objects into k non-empty subgroups is S(n,k). Here, n=10 and k=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *inclusion/exclusion* principle:

- Include the number of ways to distribute $10$ books to at most $\color\red3$ students: $\binom{3}{\color\red3}\cdot\color\red3^{10}$
- Exclude the number of ways to distribute $10$ books to at most $\color\red2$ students: $\binom{3}{\color\red2}\cdot\color\red2^{10}$
- Include the number of ways to distribute $10$ books to at most $\color\red1$ students: $\binom{3}{\color\red1}\cdot\color\red1^{10}$

Hence the total number of ways is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2}(-1)^{n}\cdot\binom{3}{3-n}\cdot(3-n)^{10}$$

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion-exclusion method gives $$3^{10}-3\cdot 2^{10}+3=55980$$ possibilities

Comment: I approved this with PARI/GP There are $55980$ strings of length $10$ with letters $1,2,3$ , such that all the $3$ letters occur at least once